# exception in file processing

Tags: java

Suppose we need to process 100 files(one by one) and if we get an exception while reading one of the file, the process should leave that file(and put contents in log) and start processing the next file:

What I think:

```
for (File f: listOfFiles) {
    try {
        //implementation of processing each file
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logging 
    }
}​
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, should work. But, you may also want to be more specific in catching Exception.

Comment: +1 for "Yes", BTW What do you mean by *be more specific in catching Exception* ??

Comment: Don't just catch "Exception" at first sight. Analyze which exceptions could be thrown by your code and catch them in the proper order, and deal with them separately.

Comment: Good ! I was looking in the other perspective..!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You are correct and put some code in finally block. I mean closing any stream or closing file itself. Similar to below pseudo-code.

```
for(File f : listOfFiles){
   try{
      //implementation of processing each file
   }catch(Exception e){
      logException(e);
   }finally{
      //close stream or file.
   }
}
```